# How to make my program "forget" the letters I have pressed on the keyboard?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Sorry for the stupid way of asking but I don't know how to say it technically.

My program is a typing trainning. I want to make a sound if the letter written by the user (userWord[i], obtained from the keyboard with getch()) is not the same as the corresponding letter from the word I give him (filas[maxIndex][i]). My code works fine, except that if for example I give him "hello" and he writes "heklo" because he is writting very fast, the Fail Sound will play 3 times (for k, l, o). I want to free somehow the buffer of the keyboard (I think this is the technical way of saying "forget the letters I pressed"), for the user to begin writing again his word without the 'k', 'l', 'o' being stored and taken as userWord[i], I tried fflush but is not working.

I am using Visual Studio

```
printf("\n\n%s\n", filas[maxIndex]); //Here it prints "Alba"

    cont = 1;

    while (cont == 1) {
        i = 0;
        while (userWord[i] != ' ') { // the user presses space to make the program know he has completed his word and wants to go to the next one

                while (!kbhit()) {}
                fflush(stdin); //I believe this should free the keyboard buffer?
                userWord[i] = getch();
                printf("%c", userWord[i]); //prints each letter the user writes each time the loop is executed, then he presses space to exit


            if (userWord[i] != filas[maxIndex][i]) {

                PlaySound(TEXT("failSound.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC); //MY PROBLEM
                cont = 1;
                Sleep(8);
                printf("\n"); //now the user should start writing his word again from the beginning
                break;
            }
            else if (filas[maxIndex][i + 1] == '\0') {
                cont = 0;
                i++;
                break;
            }
            else { cont = 0; }

            i++;
        }
        if (cont == 0) {
            userWord[i] = '\0';

            if (length != length2) { //calculated before, but irrelevant to my problem 
                cont = 1;
                Sleep(8);
                printf("\n\n%s\n", filas[maxIndex]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (cont != 3) {

        while (!kbhit()) {}
        option = getch(); // if option = '2' the user closes the program and if it equals ' ' the next word if obtained with a function and the loop begins again. 
    }
  }
```

My problem is that if he types fast because he wants to finish soon, he will make a spelling mistake (writes "Akba" instead of "Alba") and FailSound plays 3 times. I want to make something to ignore the rest of user input when he makes the mistake but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: _Note_: I might be wrong here (I don't currently have a _Win_ box to test), but I think you should add a `Sleep(1);` statement in the `while (!kbhit())` loop, otherwise the program will kill one of your processors when the user doesn't press anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't link the problem in the description to the code provided. 1: the `break` statement gets out of the __outer__ loop (as opposed to what's in the comment). Also `i` is not incremented, so the code operates on the same char of the arrays. Also how do you want it to behave if the user presses the wrong sequence slowly? _Note_: Instead of "trying to forget" the (invalid?) chars, you could discard them yourself (by not placing them into `userWord`)

Comment: I modified the code hopefully now you can understand it, sorry for the previous lack of information. Now, how could I discard the chars myself? I don't come with an idea because they are like remembered... I don`t know, they are not part of userWord yet, until I reach the getch() but then this gets them... @CristiFati

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is bad - [`fflush()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) is only valid for output streams, otherwise you get Undefined Behaviour (actually with Visual Studio it's just ignored when applied to an input stream, but this is non-standard and non-portable - either way it doesn't do what you want).

Comment: @PaulR As soon as OP uses `kbhit`, portability no longer matters... And `fflush` on input streams is documented in MS compilers. But you are right it should be avoided as much as possible!

Comment: @SergeBallesta: it's [documented for MS compilers, but it does nothing with an input stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx), so at best it's useless in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You a trying to mix low level conio input functions that directly process keyboard input with higher level stdio ones that operate on a filtered input buffer that is only available after a return has been hit.

That means that as explained by @PaulR, your `fflush(stdin)` is useless in this context, and should be avoided as non standard.

`Sleep` pauses the program for the input value as milliseconds. As far as I am concerned, I am not able to do anything in 8 ms! So the initial part of your loop could become:

```
    while (userWord[i] != ' ') { // the user presses space to make the program know he has completed his word and wants to go to the next one

            /*while (!kbhit()) {}
            fflush(stdin); // All this is useless */
            userWord[i] = getch();  // get next char from keyboard
            printf("%c", userWord[i]); //prints each letter the user writes each time the loop is executed, then he presses space to exit


        if (userWord[i] != filas[maxIndex][i]) {

            PlaySound(TEXT("failSound.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC); //MY PROBLEM
            cont = 1;
            // Sleep(8); useless
            printf("\n"); //now the user should start writing his word again from the beginning
            while (kbhit) { getch(); } // empties keyboard event queue
            break;
        }
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. However, I read in another website that if I include **<dos.h>** I could write in my code`bdos (0xC, 0, 0);` and this would clear de BIOS keyboard buffer. Do you reccommend to use this? As I am quite to programming, I don't know if an incorrect use would be "dangerous"  @SergeBallesta

Comment: Phew... `bdos(0xc, 0, 0)`! Haden't seen raw BIOS calls for decades... Honnestly I do not know whether it is supported in Windows console application, so you can just try it. But I would avoid using anything at a lower level that conio...